# What are autonomous and non-autonomous systems??

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, dynamical-systems

What are autonomous and non-autonomous systems and how are they different from each other. What are the differences between the types of systems they are describing? Do both autonomous and non-autonomous system describe dynamical systems or are dynamical systems something different?

Comment: have you tried googling ?

Comment: @onurcanbektas Yes I have...but none of the answers seem to tell me the difference between them. Mathematically I know how they are..that is their general form with non-autonomous systems being explicitly dependent on the independent variable. But how does that make it different than autonomous systems (which are still implicitly dependent on the independent-variable. They are called invaarient with time(the independent-variable) but not independent of time )

Comment: Your question is rather too broad. Do you mean nonautonomous vs. autonomous *systems of differential equations*? Then an autonomous system *of differential equations* gives rise to a (true) dynamical system. A nonautonomous system *of differential equations* gives rise to a more general object (sometimes it is called a nonautonomous dynamical system, however the terminology is not fixed). Or perhaps you have some other systems in mind?

Comment: For differential equations (ordinary, partial, with deviating argument, etc.), as well as for some integral equations, a rule of thumb is the following: the equation is called *autonomous* when for any of its solutions any (admissible) time translate of that solution is its solution, too.

Comment: @user539887 Doesn't a autonomous system of DEs describe a autonomous system (physical system or abstract system)?

Comment: I do not know what you understand under *autonomous physical system*, or *autonomous abstract system*.  In the case of the former, perhaps "the laws governing the evolution of the system do not change in time"?

Comment: @user539887 Exactly! in other words is it same as saying that the system's state variables are not changing with time?( so the state of the system is same?). ie the system will take in input and change it into output, without the system itself changing(state remains same through as the input changes to output) .

Comment: Not at all: the state variables of the system change with time, but the law governing their change does not change with time. For instance, in radioactive decay, the number of nuclei (state of the system) decreases, but according to the law (represented as decay constant, or half-life) that is constant in time.

Answer (score 4):

I assume you refer to *dynamical systems*; that is, differential equations of the form
$$ \dot x  = f(x,t,u).$$

These are classified according to which terms appear in $f(x,t,u)$:

- **Time invariant** if $f(x,t,u)=f(x,u)$ is independent of time,
- **Autonomous** if $f(x,t,u) = f(x)$ is time invariant and independent of the input.

(These definitions come from [Khalil 2001](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Nonlinear-Systems-Hassan-K-Khalil/dp/0130673897))

What is important is that  the evolution of an *autonomous* system cannot be influenced using an external input and only depends on the initial condition whereas an appropriate *controller* can change the behavior of non-autonomous systems.

Comment: Are you sure, that autonomous does include dependence on time?

Comment: I guess it depends on the definition; I have changed my answer to reflect what is in Khalil 2001.

Comment: @RiccardoSvenRisuleo Are you sure Time invariant means independent of time? I am asking because from what I understand time independent means a static system. Time invariant systems are dynamical system too in which the system in implicitly dependent on time. These are dynamical time invariant systems.

Comment: Time invariant means that if $x_1(t)$ is the response of the system started at $x_1(0)$ and $x_2(t)$ is the response of the system started at $x_1(T)$ for some $T>0$, then $x_2(t)=x_1(t)$ for all $t>T$. In other words: the response looks the same irrespective of when the system is started.

Comment: @RiccardoSvenRisuleo I have been reading up and I think I am finally beginning to understand it a little bit better. When it is said that the autonomous systems is not influenced by external input it mean that that system state variables are not changing with time and so the state of the system remain constant right?. So, if we consider the system as a black box, any input to the system,u, is interacting with a constant state system( so state variables,x, are not changing) to give an out put y(u).This will be a time-invariant system and the differential eqn decribing it are autonomous?

Comment: @GRANZER nono! The differential equation is independent of time, not the state variables! For instance $\dot x = -ax$ for some constant $a$ is independent of time and autonomous; the solution started at $x(0) = x_0$ is $x(t) = x_0 e^{-a t}$, which is a function of time.